# juju charm nova-cloud-controller exposing scheduler interface

Tags: juju, cloud, nova

I'm working on integrating a nova-cloud-controller with a custom scheduler plug-in, which requires to be installed in the same container of the nova-cloud-controller (install scheduler plug-in, filter and weigher). This task requires to modify the nova.conf. As the juju is managing the nova.conf file, we have to be able to set configs via a new interface (scheduler interface).

I'm interested in extending nova-cloud-controller charm with a scheduler interface, to be able to set the nova.conf flags:

1. compute_scheduler_driver
2. scheduler_available_filters
3. scheduler_weight_classes

This is addressed by the authors of nova-cloud-controller charm. How can we interface the scheduler use-case? Can we put it into the trunk of charm?

Also the question is to be able to react on every nova.conf modification, searching for DB and AMQP connection details. Are we able to subscribe the nova.conf modification event? Is it doable in the nova-cloud-controller charm?

Appreciate all input.